# iphone relative uptime?

Tags: iphone, timer

Is there an API accessible timer on the iPhone that does not increment when the device is sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

`mach_absolute_timer()` seems to not increment while sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting up your methods like this:

```
-(void)someMethod{
    //Whatever code you wanted to run
    [self performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

I would assume that this doesn't execute when the device is sleeping. You could of course invalidate all your timers in the appDelegate's `applicationWillEnterBackground` method, then re-enable them when you resume.

Good luck,

Zane

Comment: That would only count the foreground time of your own App. Not the uptime of the device. And besides, In that case, why not simply query the time when the app comes into foreground and query again when it goes into background.

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought by increment he meant firing.